# Why does the last letter doesn't add up where it belongs?

Tags: python

i am pretty new to coding in python and we have some programs to make for class.
The program needs to split without slicing or other functions the first part of a digit -> 12.5 becomes 12 and 5. I have so managed to make this which works only for the first part and then the last digit doesn't add up where it belongs. Could you explain me why?

```
def decoupage(nombre:str)->(str,str):
    partie_entiere = ''
    partie_decimale = ''
    delimiteurs = [',','.']
    compte = 0
    for lettre in nombre:
        if lettre not in delimiteurs:
            if compte != 1:
                partie_entiere += lettre
        elif compte == 1:
                partie_decimale += lettre
        else:
            compte += 1
    return partie_entiere, partie_decimale


assert decoupage("12.5") == ('12', '5')
assert decoupage("12,5") == ('12', '5')
assert decoupage("0.5") == ('0', '5')
assert decoupage("12") == ('12', '0')
```

Tried to execute the code line by line and then i saw the problem, 12 finishes where it belongs "partie_entiere" then "partie_decimale" doesn't have 5 in it.

Comment: The `elif compte == 1:` needs to be indented one more level to be under the `if lettre not in delimiteurs`. Right now, when you reach the decimal part, the `if lettre not in delimiteurs:` is executed but then `if compte != 1:` does not and that's it. The `elif compte == 1` will not execute because its matching `if` condition was true

Comment: Was in a rush earlier, didn't had time to add some comments with my answer. I took the liberty to change your code a bit, instead of trying to fix it. @Tomerikoo was right, your code would also have worked with the fix he suggested (and adding something to handle the last assert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

```py
def decoupage(word: str) -> tuple(str, str):
    entire_part = ''
    decimal_part = ''
    delimiters = [',','.']

    after = False # let's use a boolean to check if we are before or after the delimiter
    for letter in word:
        if not after: # if we are before
            after = letter in delimiters # populate the boolean value if we meet the delimiter
            if letter not in delimiters: # if it's not one of the delimiters
                entire_part += letter
        else:
            decimal_part += letter

    if decimal_part == '': # finally we want to add something to the decimal if an int was passed
        decimal_part = '0'

    return entire_part, decimal_part

assert decoupage("12.5") == ('12', '5')
assert decoupage("12,5") == ('12', '5')
assert decoupage("0.5") == ('0', '5')
assert decoupage("12") == ('12', '0')
```